# Subplot date formatting in Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, python-datetime

I have a 2x2 graph with date in x-axis in both graphs. I have used `datetime.strptime` to bring a *string* into `type = datetime.datetime` object format.

However I am planning to have some 12 subplots and doing this the following way seems messy.

Is there a better 'pythonic' way?

This is what I have:

````
 xx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))
 plt.grid(True)
 plt.ylabel('paramA',fontsize=8, color = "blue")
 plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
 plt.plot(date_list, myarray[:,0], '-b', label='paramA')
 plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=30, ha='right') # ha is the same as horizontalalignment

 xx = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
 xx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))
 plt.grid(True)
 plt.ylabel('paramB', 'amount of virtual mem',fontsize=8, color = "blue")
 plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
 plt.plot(date_list, myarray[:,1], '-y', label='paramB')plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=30, ha='right') # ha is the same as horizontalalignment ```
````

PS:  Initially I tried defining the plot as follows. This however did not work:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(15,15)) 
plt.title('My graph')     
for ax in enumerate(axs):
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a for loop to do it for all 12 subplots? Please explain more what exactly you want

Comment: I could not get them in a for loop. Also I wanted to use the ConciseDateFormatter in matplotlib.dates. Both gave me Attribute error inspiting of importing all the necessary modules

Comment: I answer below how to use a for loop. For rest of your questions, provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check my edited answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You failed to provide any data or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nevertheless, something like this should work. You can extend it to your real case by using desired number of rows and columns in the first command.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
labels = ['paramA', 'paramB', 'paramC', 'paramD', 'paramE', 'paramF']

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_ylabel(labels[i], fontsize=8, color="blue")
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
    ax.plot(date_list, myarray[:,i], '-b', label=labels[i])
    plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=30, ha='right') # ha is the same as horizontalalignment
```

EDIT:

Change your code to

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(15,15)) 
plt.title('My graph')     
for ax in axs:
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Hi, just updated the page to see your answer. What is the axes.flatten() doing? Maybe that was why my code did not work

Comment: @tweet: `axes` here is a 2-d object because you have multiple rows and columns in `plt.subplots()`. `axes.flatten()` converts this 2-d object into a 1-d array of axis objects which can be used in a for loop to plot one at a time. How many rows and columns do you have in the figure?

Comment: @tweet: I got it. You don;t need enumerate or flatten because you just have a single column of figures